# driver connection problems using hibernate with oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, netbeans

I'm very new using hibernate, so i'm getting problems when i try to connect to the Oracle database. I'm following step by step [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html) tutorial, but [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html#05) in the `Creating the Hibernate Reverse Engineering File` i got some errors when oracle driver tried to establish a connection. This is the exact error:

[image]

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hotel</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">hotel</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Maybe i need to set the jdbc oracle driver somewhere but i don't know exactly where. Any idea of what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle driver is not in your classpath. You need to go to the Oracle site and download the Oracle thin driver. Here is the page for 11g:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Here are the netbeans instructions for talking to oracle:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html#oci

You'll have to install the Oracle Database Instant Client first and then make sure that the ojdbc6.jar file is on your classpath.